# Pass Variables within Python Class

Tags: python

I have the following class. But when trying to pass the variable x to the re.match it doesnt appear to correctly work as whatever input I put in it returns "invalid"

```
class validate:
    def __init__(self, input_value):
        self.input_value = input_value
    def macaddress(self, oui):
        self.oui = oui
        #oui = 0, input deemed valid if it matches {OUI:DEVICE ID}.
        #oui = 1, input deemed valid if it matches {OUI}. 
        if self.oui == 0:
            x = 5
        elif self.oui == 1:
            x = 2   
        if re.match("[0-9a-fA-F]{2}([.-: ][0-9a-fA-F]{2}){x}$", self.input_value):
            return "valid"
        else:
            return "invalid"
```

Should I be passing var x in some other manner ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Insert `x` into the string this way (using [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)):

Python <2.7:

```
if re.match("[0-9a-fA-F]{2}([.-: ][0-9a-fA-F]{2}){%d}$" % x, self.input_value):
```

However if you use the python 3 way of [formatting](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), your regex interferes.
It can be cleaner (but slower) to use concatenation.

*Without concatenation:*

```
if re.match("[0-9a-fA-F]\{2\}([.-: ][0-9a-fA-F]\{2\}){0}$".format(x), self.input_value):
```

*With concatenation:*

```
if re.match("[0-9a-fA-F]{2}([.-: ][0-9a-fA-F]{2})" + x + "$", self.input_value):
```

**Note: this fails if implicit type conversion is not possible.**

If you just put `{x}` in the middle of your string, Python doesn't actually do anything with it unless string formatting is applied.